Repeat Zone Inputs Not Evaluating as Expected
I'm having a problem with a float value in a repeat node that should be increasing with each iteration but seems to be evaluating as 0, unless I look at it with a viewer node with certain geometry plugged in.
The goal is to make an array of points, space them, then instance on object on them, scaled to fit a desired total length. I can make the points and calculate their positions successfully, but spacing them is not working. I'm using a repeat node to iterate through each point, begin from a starting position, determine where the point should be and how much space the instance will take up, then add those distances to the starting position of the next point. That way each point will be positioned based on the previous point.
For some reason, the starting position input to my repeat zone that should go from 0 to 1.25 to 3.75 to 6.25 to 8.75 in the example below, seems to keep evaluating to 0. It does evaluate correctly if I look at it with a viewer node and use the geometry input of the repeat node, but evaluates to 0 when using the point that will actually use the value for its position and I have no idea why.
Instance Positions

Section for Spacing Points, Point Pos Input for the Repeat Zone seems to evaluate to 0 each iteration

If I look at the Point Pos input for the repeat zone in the 2nd iteration using the geometry input for the repeat zone, it successfully evaluates to 2.5 (the width of the previous instance). This should be added to 1.25 (half of the width of the 2nd instance) to position the 2nd point at 3.75

However, when using the geometry of the 2nd point in the viewer, the Point Pos repeat zone input now evaluates to 0 and I cannot figure out why.

I've successfully made this array work before by instancing first and then offsetting the positions of the instances instead of offsetting the point positions first. I iterated the starting position of the instances through a repeat zone very similarly to how I did it with the points and for some reason that works. I wanted to offset the points first to allow my current nodes to be adapted for making 2d and 3d arrays of points to instance on more easily but am stuck until I can figure out what's going on here.
Here is the successful implementation:

Here is the section of the successful node setup that spaces position vectors similarly

Blend file with both node trees:


In case you saw my previous bad answer, I updated it.

Since you're working with a "single" value, the "point pos" should not be a field value (something that is drawn from multiple ponts instead of a single value).
In order to really isolate it to be a single value, you should use a "sample index" to remove it from the context and make it single.
More info: https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/geometry_nodes/fields.html (specifically the "field context" part)


I would also recommend that you review all your group inputs and mark them as "single value" for every input that should not be dependent on context.
For example "array length" is very probably a single value, so mark it as single in the properties:

This transforms the dashed lines (field values) into continous lines (single values), which help you understand better what is dependent on context and what is just data.
